# In Python, is it possible to return multiple 3D array slices all at once without a for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Here is example code. I want to find the way to run the last two lines at once and return the results in the same array all at once without concatenation, is this possible?

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.ones((3,3,3))
arr[0:2,0:2,0:2]
arr[1:3,1:3,1:3]
```

The resulting command should be like

```
arr[(0:1,2:3),(0:1,2:3),(0:1,2:3)]
```

And the dimensionality of the results will be (2,2,2,2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array and slices:

```
In [128]: arr = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
In [129]: a1=arr[0:2,0:2,0:2]
     ...: a2=arr[1:3,1:3,1:3]
In [130]: a1.shape
Out[130]: (2, 2, 2)
In [131]: a2.shape
Out[131]: (2, 2, 2)
```

`a1` and `a2` are `views`, sharing the databuffer with `arr`.

Joining them on a new dimension (`np.stack` will also do this):

```
In [132]: a3 = np.array((a1,a2))
In [133]: a3.shape
Out[133]: (2, 2, 2, 2)
In [134]: a3
Out[134]: 
array([[[[ 0,  1],
         [ 3,  4]],

        [[ 9, 10],
         [12, 13]]],


       [[[13, 14],
         [16, 17]],

        [[22, 23],
         [25, 26]]]])
```

Notice how the flattened values are not contiguous (or other regular pattern).  So they have to a copy of some sort:

```
In [135]: a3.ravel()
Out[135]: array([ 0,  1,  3,  4,  9, 10, 12, 13, 13, 14, 16, 17, 22, 23, 25, 26])
```

An alternative is to construct the indices, join them, and then do one indexing.  That times about the same.  And in this case I think that would be more complicated.

===

Another way with stride_tricks.  I won't promise anything about speed.

```
In [147]: x = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(arr,(2,2,2))
In [148]: x.shape
Out[148]: (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
In [149]: x[0,0,0]
Out[149]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 3,  4]],

       [[ 9, 10],
        [12, 13]]])
In [150]: x[1,1,1]
Out[150]: 
array([[[13, 14],
        [16, 17]],

       [[22, 23],
        [25, 26]]])
In [151]: x[[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]]
Out[151]: 
array([[[[ 0,  1],
         [ 3,  4]],

        [[ 9, 10],
         [12, 13]]],


       [[[13, 14],
         [16, 17]],

        [[22, 23],
         [25, 26]]]])
```